# Building a social network using Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I'm currently developing basic social network Android app for sharing images. Already have PHP/mySQL back-end but thinking about migrating to Firebase because of some features that I like (e.g. security, fast read/write).

So, I have `users`, `posts`, `followers`, `likes`, `comments` (like every other social network nowadays).

Long story short, I want to know if I'm getting this right. 
According to [this Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/structure-data#fanout) and its example I should include unique keys from some JSON trees to others like this (example from documentation):

```
// An index to track Ada's memberships
{
  "users": {
    "alovelace": {
      "name": "Ada Lovelace",
      // Index Ada's groups in her profile
      "groups": {
         // the value here doesn't matter, just that the key exists
         "techpioneers": true,
         "womentechmakers": true
      }
    },
    ...
  },
  "groups": {
    "techpioneers": {
      "name": "Historical Tech Pioneers",
      "members": {
        "alovelace": true,
        "ghopper": true,
        "eclarke": true
      }
    },
    ...
  }
}
```

Does this mean that I will have to include keys from posts, comments, followers etc. to my users tree like this:

```
{
  "users": {
    "alovelace": {
      "name": "Ada Lovelace",
      "profileImage": "http://blabla.bla?xyzooqlL.png",
      "about:" : "Exit light, enter night",
      "country": "Neverland"
      // Index Ada's posts in her profile
      "posts": {
         // the value here doesn't matter, just that the key exists
         "post123": true,
         "post234": true
      },
      // all comments this user wrote
      "comments": {
         "comment123": true
      },
      // all posts this user liked
      "likes": {
         "post123": true
      },
      "followers": {
         "user123": true,
         "user234": true
      }
    },
    ...
  },
  "posts": {
    "post123": {
      "image": "www.bla.bla/sadsadsa.png",
      "description": "Hue hue hue",
      "likes": {
        "alovelace": true,
        "ghopper": true,
        "eclarke": true
      },
      "comments": {
        "comment123": true,
      }
    },
    "post234": {
     "image": "www.bla.bla/233arweeq.png",
      "description": "This is nice",
      "likes": {
        "eclarke": true
      },
      "comments": {
        "comment234": true,
      }
    },
  "comments": {
    "comment123": {
      "userId": "alovelace"
      "text": "cool",
      "date": "current"
    }
   },
    ...
  }
}
```

Isn't it a little too much if I have for example 5000 followers, 2000 followings, 1500 post likes? **When fetching user or any other object I will also fetch all its keys within that object**. Imagine fetching 15 very active users with all this data.

If you have any suggestions how should I structure data, please let me know. **Any kind of feedback will be useful.**

Thanks.

Comment: Storage is cheap, the user's time is not. See [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/) and [Firebase for SQL developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s).

Comment: Thank you for your quick response @FrankvanPuffelen! Storage is cheap, but I am not looking at it just from server side of view. That data will be downloaded on a mobile device (currently on Android phones) so it's not just about server storage.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. You should only download data that you'll display to the user. The data structure nor the documentation say anything to contradict that (unless a bug snuck in there of course).

Comment: If I fetch user with id "alovelace" in this case, I will also fetch everything inside it, including thousands of rows related to comments, likes, posts... Anyways thank you for these two links.

Comment: If the downloading of both the name and long list of members is a concern, you should split them into two separate nodes: `/groups/$groupid` and `/members/$groupid`.